# PLSQL "error Cursor already open"

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE 
  f_cd fee.fee_cd%type;
  f_name fee.fee_nm%type; 
  f_new_cd fee.new_fee_cd%type;
  f_new_name fee.new_fee_nm%type;

  Cursor cur is
    SELECT Fee_cd, fee_nm, new_fee_cd, new_fee_nm FROM Fee;
BEGIN
  if cur%ISOPEN then
    close cur;
  end if;

  open cur;

  for rec in cur loop
    fetch cur INTO f_cd, f_name, f_new_cd, f_new_name;
    dbms_output.put_line ('The Fee Code ' || f_cd
                          || ' is the one you selected and it''s name is '
                          || f_name);
  end loop;

  close cur;
END;
```

But I keep getting the error message

**Cause:**    An attempt was made to open a cursor that was already open.

**Action:**   Close cursor first before reopening.

I don't know what is happening.  When I alter the code to take away the `for loop` and use just the `loop... end loop` structure it works.  Functioning code below:

```
loop
  fetch cur INTO f_cd, f_name, f_new_cd, f_new_name;
  dbms_output.put_line ('The Fee Code ' || f_cd
                        || ' is the one you selected and it''s name is '
                        || f_name);    
  exit when cur%notfound;
end loop;

close cur;
END;
```

Why when I use the for loop does it tell me the cursor is already open?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are opening the cursor:

```
open cur;
```

and then without closing it, you open again in the cursor loop:

```
for rec in cur loop
```

The "for cursor loop" construct opens the cursor first.  No need to open it beforehand.  See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155):

"The cursor FOR LOOP statement implicitly declares its loop index as a record variable of the row type that a specified cursor returns, and then opens a cursor. "

Answer (score 4):

Two ways for using `Cursor` :

1. `OPEN` ; `FETCH INTO` ;`CLOSE`;
2. `FOR I IN C1`;

**METHOD 1:** `OPEN C1`; `LOOP` ; `FETCH C1 INTO` ; `END LOOP`; `CLOSE C1`;

```
DECLARE
v_code_id   your_users.cod_id%type;  
v_code_user your_users.cod_user%type ;
cursor C_users is select cod_id,cod_user from your_users where 1=1; 
BEGIN
OPEN C_users;  --opening cursor
loop
Fetch C_users into v_code_id,v_code_user; -- Fetching from Cursoe
exit when C_users%NOTFOUND;
DELETE from your_users WHERE cod_emp  IN (v_code_id);
dbms_output.put_line( 'USER : ' || ' ' ||  v_code_user || ' is deleted.' );
End Loop;
commit;
Close C_users ; --Closing Cursor
END;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
USER :  mahi is deleted.
USER :  xyz is deleted.

Statement processed.
```

**METHOD 2 :** `FOR i in C1`; `LOOP` ; `END LOOP`

```
DECLARE
cursor C_users is
 select cod_id,cod_user from your_users where 1=1; 
BEGIN
For rec in C_users 
loop
 DELETE from your_users WHERE cod_emp  IN (rec.cod_id );
 dbms_output.put_line( 'USER : ' || ' ' ||  rec.cod_user || ' is deleted.' );
End Loop;
commit;
END;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
USER :  xyz is deleted.
USER :  mahi is deleted.
```